# Set bitmap_image and checkbox in grid view

Tags: android

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference at com.example.piker.MultipleShareActivity$ImageAdapter1.getView(MultipleShareActivity.java:153)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.e("122","after");
    int width = getScreenWidth();
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    linearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lins);
    ImageView iv=new ImageView(con);
    ImageView iv;
    iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ims);
    CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(con);
    iv.setImageBitmap(mThumb[0]);// finding error in this line & mthumb is bitmap array//
    linearLayout.addView(iv);
    linearLayout.addView(cb);
    return linearLayout;
}
```

Comment: check mThumb[0] as null or not

Comment: it is clearly your mThumb[] is empty, make sure you are presenting problem not junks.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
convertView.findViewById
```

in imageview and linearlayout